# Upgraded .NET Framework to 4.6.1 and getting socket exceptions

Tags: c#, socketexception, .net-4.6.1

Initially my project was on `.NET` framework 4.5 and then I migrated it to `.NET` framework 4.6.1 And Now, I am getting Socket Exceptions which was not there earlier with `.NET` 4.5

Error message as:

> Inner Exception           ---------------             Type :
>   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>             Message : The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused
>   by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being
>   exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue.
>   Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9900000'.
>
> Inner Exception
>                 ---------------
>                 Type : System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>                 Message : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Can anyone please tell, how upgrade in `.NET` framework is affecting it and what should be the solution?

Comment: How did you "migrate" the application? Did you just change the target framework of the project? Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: There's no problem with 4.6.1. The error complains that the *remote* server closed the connection.

Comment: I changed the target framework of project in Visual Studio under properties -> Application -> Target framework. And then build the application code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but it works in .NET 4.5 Then why not in 4.6.1 ?

Comment: We don't know, because you won't share code that exhibits the problem. I can guarantee you that others have successfully used sockets in 4.6.1.

Comment: Just spitballing, but could there be an issue with the key token? Look closely there and you may find something.

Answer (score 2):

This might be caused from the server/host security settings. To change security settings you set following before calling remote data:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

System.Net.SecurityProtocolType enum contains all options. If you need multiple seperate them with or (|)

Comment: Upvoted as this sounds very likely to be caused by the change in default behaviour for choosing the TLS security version.

Comment: There's no indication at all that OP is using secure sockets.